# How to add header in Dart Post Request

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  static Future<List<Storedata>> fetchStoredata() async {
    const baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.104:8000/v1/';
    var storeDataResponse = await client.post(
      Uri.parse('$baseUrl/me'),
      headers: {"app_id": "${Storedata().appId}"},
    );
    if(storeDataResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      return 
    }
  }
```

The Storedata().appId is Model of Json Data is this format is Correct

Answer (score 0):

You can call **getHeader** Function in all your requests and customize it,
you can check an example header function

```dart
Future<Map<String, String>> getHeader() async {
  
  var platform = Platform.isAndroid ? PlatformTypes.ANDROID : PlatformTypes.IOS;
  var locale = Intl.getCurrentLocale();
  locale = locale.split("_").first;
  var deviceId = DeviceInfo.getInstance()?.deviceID ?? "";
  var model = DeviceInfo.getInstance()?.model ?? "";
  
  return {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "locale": locale,
    "platform": platform,
    "device-id": deviceId,
  };
}
```

```
var header = await getHeader();
final response = await client.post(Uri.parse(_baseUrl + url),
      headers: header, body: body);
```